# Prevent running watchEffect function after app mounts in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I use the `onMounted` + `watchEffect` for some expensive rendering

right now every time the app mounts the `watchEffect` function runs also

how can I run a function only when the app mounts

and prevent `watchEffect` run automatically --> only run it
after props value changes

```
// parent

<template>
  <child :data="data" />

  <button type="button" @click="changeData">click to change</button>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./components/child.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Child,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      data: [1],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    changeData() {
      this.data = [1, 2];
    },
  },
};
</script>

// Child



<template>
  <h1>I have this prop</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref, watchEffect } from "@vue/runtime-core";

export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["data"],

  setup(props) {
    onMounted(() => {

// do this 

      watchEffect(() => {
        // if props.data data changes do this
      });
    });

    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `watchEffect` will fire immediately on setup and also when it’s dependencies change. Therefore if you want to stop the first invocation during setup, use `watch` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question right, it should run, when the app mounts, but also not when it mounts?
Anyway, you can use `watchEffect` directly in the `setup` method, why nest it in the `onMounted`. And if you only want to listen to changes of the props, use just `watch` instead. `watchEffect` runs it once when it's mounted and then when any of the used props or refs are changed.

```
<template>
  <h1>I have this prop</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, watch, watchEffect } from "@vue/runtime-core";

export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["data"],

  setup(props) {
    onMounted(() => {
      // do stuff once 
    });
    watchEffect(() => {
      // if mounted or if props.data data changes do this
    });
    watch(
      () => props.data,
      (data, prevData) => {
        // if props.data data changes do this
      }
    );

    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more suggestion added to Thomas answer is to use `watchEffect` with `flush` option as `post`

This will ensure that all your refs are also resolved

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#callback-flush-timing

```js
<template>
  <h1>I have this prop</h1>
</template>

<script>
import { watchEffect, watchPostEffect } from "@vue/runtime-core";

export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["data"],

  setup(props) {
    watchEffect(() => {
      // if mounted or if props.data data changes do this
    }, { flush: 'post' });

    // Vue 3.2+
    watchPostEffect(() => {
      // if mounted or if props.data data changes do this
    });

    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: The link in your answer is invalid. Would you be so kind and update it for future reference?